# Error when trying to define object of class type that is derived from an abstract class

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class, virtual-functions

```
class Road {
private:
    std::vector<Vehicle*> container;
public:
    std::vector<Vehicle*> getContainer(){
        return container;
    }
    virtual void operator+(Vehicle *vehicle)=0;
};


class Highway: public Road {
public:
    virtual void operator+(Vehicle *vehicle) {
         getContainer().push_back(vehicle);
     }
};
```

Why do I get an error that I cannot allocate an object of abstract type when all of my virtual functions are overriden?
It happens when I try to call `Road r = Highway();` in my main class.

Comment: `getContainer` must return a reference to `container` member variable. In your code every time you call `getContainer()` you are returning a copy of `container` member variable.

Comment: @cokceken: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: _"It happens when I try to call `Road r = Highway();` in my main class."_ What is your goal with this line of code? What are you attempting to do? Only knowing that can we tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For `Road r = Highway();`, `Road r` means you're trying to define an object of type `Road`, which is an abstract class then the definition is not allowed. The initializer list part (i.e. `= Highway()`) doesn't affect the type of `r`, it just means `r` is [slicing-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) initialized from an temporary object of type `Highway`.

You should use pointers/smart pointers or references with abstract class type, e.g.

```
Road* r = new Highway;
// using r ...
delete r;
```

or

```
Highway h;
Road& r = h;
// using r ...
```

Comment: Also note that even if it were possible, assigning a `Highway` to a `Road` [would cause data slicing](http://ideone.com/BdVS4L).